# html video wont play on google chrome but will play on firefox but different

Tags: css, html, video

Trying to play a video within a text on google chrome, It only shows a screenshot of the video but does not play the whole clip. it is able to show the display of the video in the text. however, on Firefox it plays the whole video but does not show it in the text. it seems it can not find the text info i have in my script or just ignores it. very strange.

```js
document.getElementById('bg').play();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
         
#bg {
    height: 700px;
    width: 1250px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
         
}
    
#info {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30em;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    fill: #000;
}
    
#masked {
    mask:url("#maskLayer");
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100vh">
    <mask id="maskLayer">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"></rect>
        <text x="8%" y="55%" id="info">
            JSC
        </text>
    </mask>

    <rect id="masked" width"100%" height="100%" fill="#f5f5f5"></rect>
</svg>
<video src="Untitled.mov" id="bg" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

Comment: Why have you called a play() when you already have autoplay?

Comment: because i was searching my problem online and some people have suggested to have a play script to solve the problem. this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
nevermind! managed to work out what was wrong with it. just needed to mute the video! 

    <svg width="100%" height="100vh">
    <mask id="maskLayer">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"></rect>
        <text x="8%" y="55%" id="info">JSC
    </mask>

    <rect id="masked" width"100%" height="100%" fill="#f5f5f5"></rect>
</svg>
        <video src="Untitled.mp4" id="bg" autoplay loop
        muted>
        </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "**muted**" was the Problem.

In your first post you used "Untitled.**mov**".

In your second post you used "Untitled.**mp4**".

If the problem was the format - you can use the video unmuted.

Kind regards